# SP page deployed, but the content is old

Tags: javascript, deployment, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

I have a simple setup - SharePoint Foundation Server and Visual Studio 2013 Professional installed on this server. Everything worked fine. Until... I don't know why, but deployment stopped refreshing content on the page.

I have some javascript code on my page (inside aspx page or in external js file). When I change it (e.g. output sth else to console) I still see the effect of some previous build. It looks like deploy operation does nothing. The most puzzling part I think is when I click *Debug* button. One would expect it to work at least there. But it doesn't.

Two other developers working on the same environment (same server) have no problems with changing their JS code.

The only hint I have is this error msg:

```
0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.
```

I see it when I run *Debug* from VS. It is thrown at line `if (!IsNullOrUndefined(window.localStorage) && IsNullOrUndefined(window.localStorage.SPAnimationEnabled))` of `core.debug.js` file from SP core.

Can anyone help me? I don't even know how to google it :s

Oh, I should also mention that I did `clean` and `rebuild all` but nothing helped. Also there are no errors thrown - either on VS output or in event viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project was under svn, so I fixed it by checking out to other directory. And it works just fine. I guess it had sth to do with permissions.